# Build EntityManagerFactory using Hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm building a web application using SpringFramework. In the data access layer I was using Hibernate to query data in MySQL, which was working fine. My `SessionFactory` is build from this method:

```
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    return new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
            .configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Today I'm going to integrate my data access with JPA, which needs a `EntityManagerFactory`, IMO I only need to change the code above into the following:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws HibernateException {
    return new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
            .configure()                
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
```

simply because `SessionFactory` extends `EntityManagerFactory`. However I got an exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to
>   javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

This is quite weird, because `SessionFactoryImpl` implements `SessionFactory` while `SessionFactory` extends `EntityManagerFactory`. I don't know why the cast fails.

My question is: 1. why the cast is invalid?  2. what's the correct way to build a `EntityManagerFactory` using Hibernate?

**EDIT** Debugger says

```
factory instanceof SessionFactory         //true
factory instanceof EntityManagerFactory   //false
```

and the source of `SessionFactory`

```
public interface SessionFactory extends EntityManagerFactory, HibernateEntityManagerFactory, Referenceable, Serializable, Closeable
```

I'm sure all the above `EntityManagerFactory` refers to `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: Any reason why you'd do it in such a complicated way? Why not just inject the entityManager into your beans using the @PersistenceContext annotation?

Comment: @wallenborn I'm new to Java(as well as spring framework) so I don't know what's the best practice. Since my "old code" provides a `SessionFactory`, my first idea is re-using it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, unless you're using Hibernate 5.2 Hibernate's org.hibernate.SessionFactory does not extend javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory, hibernate-entitymanager was only recently merged into hibernate-core. Seems to me that you're browsing source code from a version newer than the one you're using in your project.

In either case, to see the correct way of using Hibernate with JPA, refer to [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_jpa).

Comment: I'm using `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.1.Final` so I'm sure `SessionFactory` extends `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`. And my project has `hibernate-core` dependency only, no `hibernate-entitymanager`.

Comment: In that case, my only guess is that Hibernate is returning a class that is created an instrumented by CGLib. You can try printing the instance that gets returned and try debugging from there. In either case, to see the correct way of using Hibernate with JPA, refer to [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_jpa)

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the Session factory by following the steps [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html), setting up the SessionFactory bean in Spring.

But since you've already coded in terms of the EntityManagerFactory, you should follow the easier route described in [this tutorial](http://www.patrick-gotthard.de/einfuehrung-in-spring-data-jpa-mit-hibernate) It's in German, unfortunately, but the code should speak for itself. You declare Hibernate as your JPA vendor, then the EntityManagerFactory with the vendor and the datasource, which can be defined explicitly or be a JNDI datasource, defined in your container and requested like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="myDataSource"/>
```

And then it's very nice to declare a Spring transactionManager to allow the @Transactional annotation so you won't have to deal with explicit transaction management.

Then you can let your UserDAO look like this:

```
public class UserDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

     @Transactional
     public List<User> findUserByName(String name) {
         return em.createNamedQuery("User.findByName")
           .setParameter("name", name)
           .getResultList();
     }
}
```

where User is something like

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery( name="User.findByName", query="select u from User where u.name = :name") })
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
...
}
```

There's many ways to do this, though.